# Cant see Scala class in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, class, intellij-idea

Im new to intelliJ IDEA, now I have followed the tutorial on jetbrains - Creating and running your scala application - which I can follow until when I get to the section Creating an object. It says in the project tree, right-click a node in which you want to create your Scala object. *From the drop-down list, select Scala class.* But there is no Scala class? What have I done wrong? I have followed the tutorial exactly to this point.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-running-your-scala-application.html

Comment: Well, you cannot select _any_ node in the tree, it has to be marked as _source folder_ (blue icon).